# Release Pipeline Job Concurrency

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

I recognize it's a bad idea to run release pipeline tasks concurrently among agents within a deployment group- a failure across all of them simultaneously could be very bad in certain, common conditions.

However, is there a way for the deployment groups within a stage to kick off their tasks concurrently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you can split multiple deployment groups into multiple stages, and run a deployment group in one stage, so that you can run them in parallel.

[image]

Comment: Yes, there are multiple deployment group jobs in a stage but I would like them to execute in parallel rather than serially. It seems the available conditions do not allow for that behavior.

Comment: As a workaround, you can split multiple deployment groups into multiple stages, and run a deployment group in one stage, so that you can run them in parallel.

Comment: Brilliant, so much so I wouldn't consider this a workaround. Rather, I'd consider it a valid use case for additional stages of which I had not considered. I'll play around with this in the next day or so and report on the outcomes. Likely the perfect solution, thank you.

Comment: Accepted as answer. Thank you, the pipeline completes much more efficiently now.